# Angular material: How to hide window scrollbar when mat-drawer is open?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

**Scenario :**

- I am trying to use a mat-drawer like a modal sidesheet.
- So when the drawer is open I don't want the user to be able to interact with anything outside of the sidesheet. This means that I don't want the user to be able to scroll the window when the sidesheet is open.

  Is there a way to make it so that when the drawer is open scrolling is disabled and the scrollbar disappears?

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fuasta) is an example demonstrating the problem. Notice how when the drawer is open the page's scrollbar is still there and you can scroll the window as well as the drawer content.

- How can I make this scrollbar disappear so that the user can only interact with the content of the drawer?

Comment: Why is your app nested in a 2000px high `div`?

Comment: Just so that the scrollbar appears

Comment: @phelhe I have included my solution. It works on my demo. Let me know if it works on your app!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why in the blazes does you div need to have a height of 2000 pixels, but anyways, here's a way to solve it.

On your app.component.css, add the following CSS properties `overflow: auto` and `overscroll-behavior-y: contain` to prevent the scrolling behaviour from 'escaping' your mat-drawer.

In a way, we can say that this creates a logical separation between the drawer's scrolling context and main application.

```
.drawer-content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
  background: orange;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding-left: 20px;

  overflow: auto;
  overscroll-behavior-y: contain;
}
```

I have reproduced the demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spehcr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css). (I have left the other classes and CSS properties untouched.)